# Binomial coefficient in C#

Tags: c#

Hi I need to find an algorithm to compute the binomial coefficient. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYHyz.jpg
n is 3, while k must go from 0 to 3.

I found this link with the code which explains how to calculate the binomial coefficient http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/calculate-the-binomial-coefficient-n-choose-k-efficiently-in-c/ but I don't know how to do when k is not assigned.

This is the code I found:

```
decimal result = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= K; i++)
{
    result *= N - (K - i);
    result /= i;
}
return result;
```

Comment: You have to set N and K before the code, right? So what's the problem I could not understand.

Comment: Do you want to get 4 results for (n,k) as (3,0), (3,1), (3,2) and (3,3)?

Comment: Yes @balayoglu any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to calculate 4 coefficients; each for every term of the binomial:

```
decimal[] result = new decimal[N + 1];
for (int k = 0; k <= N; k++)
{
    result[k] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        result[k] *= N - (k - i);
        result[k] /= i;
    }
}
return result;
```

Comment: Hi @AbdelAziz AbdelLatef thank you. Unfortunately your code takes more than 15 minutes and then it crashes. What should I do?

Comment: I tried it and it gave me the expected results "1, 3, 3, 1". Show me how you used it, and the error you got.